# Unit testing - unexpected result from lambda expression in mock object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, moq, xunit

I am writing some unit tests. One of the tests I have written has unexpected behavior and I am confused about what has happened exactly. The problem is in mocking `GetAsync` method. When I use a variable like `limit`, the code does not work correctly, but if I use const instead of variables it works fine. Here is my source code:

```
namespace TestClass
{
    public class LambdaTest<T> where T : TestModel
    {
        readonly List<T> _list = new List<T>();
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _list.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> TestMethod()
        {
            int limit = 100;
            var result = GetAsync(p => !p.IsDeleted && (DateTime.Now - p.CreationDate).TotalHours < limit);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class TestModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the Test project:

```
namespace TestClass.Tests
{
    public class ExpressionTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SimpleTest()
        {
            var returnValue = new List<TestModel>
            {
                new TestModel() {CreationDate = DateTime.Now, Id = 1},
                new TestModel() {CreationDate = DateTime.Now, Id = 2}
            };
            var sut = new Mock<LambdaTest<TestModel>>();
            int limit = 100;
            sut.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(p => !p.IsDeleted && (DateTime.Now - p.CreationDate).TotalHours < limit))
               .Returns(returnValue);

            var result = sut.Object.TestMethod();

            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I can not use const here. I know about expression tree and some other subjects related to this problem, but can anyone explain what is happening exactly here and how can I solve this problem?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Moq can't match the expressions which is why the result is false

Comment: thanks, @Nkosi , so is there any way to change the expression to solve this problem? (if I use const digits it works fine) , and if not, is there any way to write a good test method?

Comment: How `_list` get populated in `TestClass`?

Comment: @Fabio , it doesn't matter, you can consider it something like: `var returnValue = new List<TestModel>
            {
                new TestModel() {CreationDate = DateTime.Now, Id = 1},
                new TestModel() {CreationDate = DateTime.Now, Id = 2}
            };`

Comment: If you have access to the list, you don't need mocks, just fill the list, run `TestMethod` and check that expected result returned.

Comment: dear @Fabio I simplified the scenario, my environment is not exactly like this, I have several layers and the list is filled at runtime by the database and I have to mock objects.

Comment: My point is, that instead of mocking things, you should test actual implementation. Even better you have data in the list, it is already in a memory.

Comment: @Fabio , in many cases you are testing a layer like service layer and it is not good to involve other layers and dependencies (like a repository layer) in your tests. additionally, sometimes you don't have access to the other layers or database and you have to use a mock object instead of real data. on the other hand, a basic rule of unit testing is writing tests for each small unit of the code (like a method) without involving the other dependencies in your test.

Comment: @Pedram, this is a different interpretation of unit tests - common one. Which will introduce problems you has. Another interpretation is where unit - is unit of behaviour. Where you will mock only dependencies which makes your tests slow(external resource) or very very complicated to setup, there you can introduce mocks. In your case you already has data in memory which you can preconfigure for tests, then you need only define expected result and run test with all dependencies included.

Comment: @Fabio yes you are right, but I don't have access to actual data and I have to do the tests on that way because of the test policy here. I think I found the solution for the problem, I will post it soon, many thanks to you for your help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. I simulated the method behavior by something like this:

```
sut.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(
                It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TestModel, bool>>>()
            ))
            .Returns((Expression<Func<TestModel, bool>> predict) =>
            {
                var result = _list.Where(predict.Compile());
                return Task.FromResult(result);
            });
```